# IIS refuses to serve static .gltf files

Tags: iis, static-content

I am using [three.js library](https://threejs.org/) with [GLTFLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js). I downloaded some free 3D model with [.gltf extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF) (it also came with a .bin file, and a folder with textures).

I can access every other file in this folder from IIS (10) as static content, except for the .gltf file which returns the 404 page.

I have added MIME mapping to IIS everywhere at this point (web.config for the ASP.NET Core 2.2 site, top level of IIS, site level of IIS). It is model/gltf+json. I tried application/json and application/octet-stream just in case. It returns 404 in all situations.

I tried allowing the server to serve all static files with a wildcard MIME mapping. Even this fails.

If I rename the .gltf file to .json, it works fine.

I tried FailedRequestTracing, which provided me with a huge xml file. Going through that revealed nothing enlightening to me, but maybe I just don't know enough about inner workings of IIS.

Same trouble on IISExpress (ran from Visual Studio 2019).

I tried converting .gltf to .glb using https://glb-packer.glitch.me/ but .glb extension exhibits the same issue with IIS -> 404.

Restarting IIS with `iisreset /restart` didn't help.

I am not using any URL rewrite rules.

Adding the option `ServeUnknownFileTypes = true` to StaticFiles middleware made no difference.

Have you encountered a problem like this before? Any suggestions as to what to try next?

UPDATE: I have managed to narrow down the problem to AspNetCoreModuleV2 handler. When not present, .gltf file is served correctly. Now, I do need this module to run, so that's a problem.

UPDATE: figured it out finally... I'll post an answer for the next unfortunate soul to stumble upon this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I am using a custom FileServerProvider because I need IoC container to inject it into some controllers later on. (Similar fix works on UseStaticFiles() in Configure method, if the .gltf is in wwwroot.)

In ConfigureServices:

```
var fileProviderOptions = new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(_ContentStorePath),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/ContentStore")
};
fileProviderOptions.StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)fileProviderOptions
    .StaticFileOptions.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings[".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json";
services.AddSingleton<IFileServerProvider>(new FileServerProvider(
    new List<FileServerOptions> { fileProviderOptions }
));
```

So, I had to tell it what gltf is in code. StaticFileOptions is read-only, and ContentTypeProvider is an interface, so a few hoops need jumping through.

In retrospect, maybe this question was better suited to StackOverflow after all.

Answer (score 1):

Thank your for this post, extremely helpful.

I was getting this error 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'
iis 10 hosted angular 11 scaffolded by core .net5 site using GLTFLoader for .glb files.

This code in Startup.cs fixed issue:

`StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider() }; ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings.Add( new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".glb", "model/gltf-buffer")); app.UseStaticFiles(options);`

In addition; glb file had to be placed in the site /assets folder where favicon.ico lives.
NOT /ClientApp/dist/assets

Your angular.json file has this entry:
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets"
],

Note: setting the sites IIS mime mappings and/or handler mappings had no effect here.

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.cs file, update the Configure function to include the following code

```
    var options = new StaticFileOptions {
        ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
    };
    ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".obj", "text/plain"));

    app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```